# How can I define a type, that represents all binary or unary function taking ArgType as arguments and returning ReturnType?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a `type` `UnaryOrBinaryFunc`, that could conceptually be defined like this:

```
 type A = ArgType => ReturnType
 type B = (ArgType, ArgType) => ReturnType
 type UnaryOrBinaryFunc = <Some code saying that UnaryOrBinaryFunc is either a A or a B>
```

in my code I tried to define `UnaryOrBinaryFunc` as:
`type UnaryOrBinaryFunc = A with B`
and it seemed to be acceptable for Eclipse, I sadly didn't find anything
about using the `with` keyword in association with the `type` keyword on the Internet.

Now if you want a little bit of context on why I want to do that, I wrote something that looks like what I want to accomplish inside my project:

```
 sealed trait Token
 case object AND extends Token
 case object NOT extends Token

 type ArgType
 type ReturnType

 type A = ArgType => ReturnType
 type B = (ArgType, ArgType) => ReturnType
 type UnaryOrBinaryFunc = A with B

 def f: A = ???
 def g: B = ???

 Map[TokenType, UnaryOrBinaryFunc] (
    NOT -> f,
    AND -> g
 )
```

Notice that I used `???`for the definitions of f and g because I didn't want to bother defining them.

Now I get the following error, the same as in my project:

```
type mismatch; found : TypeDecl.A (which expands to) TypeDecl.ArgType ⇒
 TypeDecl.ReturnType required: TypeDecl.UnaryOrBinaryFunc (which expands to)
 TypeDecl.ArgType ⇒ TypeDecl.ReturnType with (TypeDecl.ArgType,  
 TypeDecl.ArgType) ⇒ TypeDecl.ReturnType
```

I really don't know how to do that, anyone has an idea of how I could define `UnaryOrBinaryFunc` so I don't have to modify what is inside my `Map`?

Many thanks.

Comment: do you really need to define A and B as a type? Maybe it's better to define it as a `traits`?

Comment: I don't think I could because I am working on a project that I am not the creator of, and I have to keep the initial class definitions as they were before, in the project `ArgType` is an expression tree, as well as `ReturnType`.
So in the end I am trying to create a `Map` linking Tokens like `Not`, `And`, `Times`, etc.. to their respective expression tree representation(an Expression tree can take one or two expression trees at its creation).
Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly....

There are several ways of defining a coproduct in Scala.

The simplest, and probably the best with just two types is to use `Either`:

```
type UnaryOrBinaryFunc =
  Either[(ArgType, ArgType) => ReturnType, ArgType => ReturnType]

Map[TokenType, UnaryOrBinaryFunc] (
    NOT -> Left(f),
    AND -> Right(g)
 )
```

You can write some aliases for Left and Right to make things more readable.

If you are using the Shapeless library, you can implement this with Coproducts as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560546/how-to-implement-an-heterogeneous-container-in-scala) question:

```
type UnaryOrBinaryFunc =
  (ArgType, ArgType) => ReturnType :+: ArgType => ReturnType
```

With plain scala, it's also possible to use a trick to create coproducts using implicits as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)

```
sealed trait UnaryOrBinaryFunc
object UnaryOrBinaryFunc {
  implicit object UnaryFunc extends UnaryOrBinaryFunc[ArgType => ReturnType]
  implicit object BinaryFunc extends UnaryOrBinaryFunc[(ArgType, ArgType) => ReturnType]
}
```

Every function that processes UnaryOrBinaryFunc should take an implicit parameter of UnaryOrBinaryFunc as shown in the link given.

... However, I would question whether this complexity is necessary.  To solve this problem I would do one of:

- Define your functions to take `List`s or `Product`s, and switch on their lengths at runtime.

  ```
  type UnaryOrBinaryFunc = Seq[ArgType] => ReturnType
  ```
- Keep Unary and Binary functions separate, and make generic any functions that must process either.

  ```
  val unaryFns = Map[TokenType, UnaryFunc] (
    NOT -> f,
    ...
  )

  val binaryFns = Map[TokenType, BinaryFunc] (
    AND -> g,
    ...
  )

  def processUnaryOrBinaryFn[T](fn: T) = {
    ...
  }
  ```

Which of all the above solutions is most appropriate will depend on what else you need to do :-).

Comment: Awesome answer can't wait to dive into all this!!